# Recording shell output for interactive commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, interactive, io-redirection

While looking into a shell redirection problem, I found a couple of answers that pointed me to the `script` command. As I understand it, script just records in- and output of the terminal, and allows me to read that from a file later. It covers some edge cases that don't work with regular bash redirection (`2>&1 > /tmp/log`), but, from the man page:

> Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the typescript file. Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal.

Similarly, also from the man page and probably related:

> **BUGS**
>       Script places everything in the log file, including linefeeds and backspaces.  This is not what the naive user expects.

Is there a better way to record an interactive terminal program that also catches output from sub-processes, but doesn't suffer from these problems? Are there alternatives to `script`?

Related questions: [bash redirection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75327/redirection-doesnt-work), [stdout+stderr does not redirect everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988279/bash-redirecting-of-stdoutput-and-stderror-does-not-catch-all-output)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You can postprocess the output to clean it up, although lamentably there is not a standard utility which does this.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a tool that does exactly that which script does, but for interactive programs, in particular the changes on the terminal. That way I can easily record an entire session, including any changes I make to files (such as configuration files or gdb output), which could be really useful to create tutorials or replayable live demonstrations.

Comment: `script` is all about interactive programs.  What it is not about is I/O that is received from or delivered to anything other than the standard streams.  Moreover, it is a general-purpose program -- it records, but it does not *interpret*.  If you need more than that then it probably needs to be specifically tailored to your particular use.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698590/how-to-capture-all-the-commands-typed-in-unix-linux-by-any-user and http://serverfault.com/questions/470755/log-all-commands-run-by-admins-on-production-servers... I would also suggest posting your question on the Unix & Linux stack exchange, as your question is not specifically programming related. Also, check out ttyrec -- http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en

Comment: Video recordings don't suffer from these problems.

Comment: Try [Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam)

Comment: `script` has an option to include timestamps in the typescript, specifically as support for the scenario you seem to be looking for.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240796/gnu-screen-how-to-enable-or-disable-logging-while-screen-is-already-attached hope still intersted :))))