# GNU Screen: How to enable or disable logging while screen is already attached?

Tags: command-line, terminal, logs, gnu-screen

Suppose I have an attached screen, but I forgot to execute `screen -L` initially. Is it possible to enable and disable the logging of the currently attached screen without re-executing screen?

I know that it's possible to take what is essentially a screenshot of a currently attached screen by pressing `Ctrl+a h` (that key combo followed by `h`), but I want to enable persistent logging of the attached screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To enable logging on the current window of a screen session, press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> (uppercase H, <kbd>Shift+H</kbd> if you prefer).

That actually toggles the logging state (so if the windows was being logged beforehand, it is now no longer logged).

That's the `log` command in `screen`, so you can also do <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> and enter `log` (or `log on` to turn it on instead of toggling the state), or run `screen -X log on` within the shell running in the current window.

To enable logging on all windows, use the `at` command to apply that to all windows:

```
screen -X at '#' log on
```

Or press, <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> and enter `at \# log on`.

For more details, see:

```
info -f screen --index-search=at
info -f screen --index-search=log
```

Comment: All I did was Ctrl+ a + : and then typed `log on` at the prompt.  Did not need to use `at \#`.  Anyone else confirm?

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, `log on` is just the equivalent of `^A H`, it only logs the current window. You need `at # log on` to do that for every window.

Comment: Ctrl + a + h creates a hardcopy.0 file of the current screen.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, yes and Ctrl + a H (capital h, shift + h) toggles logging for the current Window as this answer is saying.